# Store third party API key in S3 bucket or Dynamod DB?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-dynamodb, public-key-encryption

I am connecting my app to third party email service using the registered API key.

Since it is a sensitive information I would like to store it in some encrypted place and retrieve it from there.
As I am already using AWS Lambda, so for this use-case is it better to use Dynamo DB or S3 bucket to store the API key?

Comment: you can set it as an environment variable on the lambda, lambda supports encrypting environment variables using `KMS` . but its encryption at test. anyone with access can see the actual value

Comment: Also the AWS Secrets Manager might be a good option.

Answer (score 1):

Parameter store is also a good option. It is possible to store encrypted data and more easy to manage than via Secret Manager.
https://aws.amazon.com/en/systems-manager/features/

Answer (score 0):

For my future projects, I would store secrets in the SSM ParameterStore and then make the secrets available to my lambdas as encrypted during the deployment phase. The lambdas can then use the KMS key to decrypt it during runtime.

The parameter store has a 120 requests per second limit, this way we can prevent us from hitting the limit.

Answer (score 0):

For just storing API key, both `S3` and `DynamoDB` are not the best option.

The simplest solution will be `SecureString` in `ParameterStore`.

Alternatively, you can use lambda encrypted environment variable if you want to encrypt with a specific KMS key. Then in your lambda code you decrypt the env variable.

If you do the second approach in many lambdas, then consider put this code for decryption in a lambda layer.

Comment: How to access parameterStore, do you mean Secrets Manager?

Comment: Found it myself